# usb 2-3: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM

Tags: arch-linux, usb, suspend

I'm running Arch Linux on a Lenovo Thinkpad X280. I'm trying to improve energy consumption, particularly when suspended.

I have s0i3 sleep support enabled as per the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_6)) by using the kernel command line parameter `acpi.ec_no_wakeup=1`. I also have the BIOS set as follows:

```
Config -> Thunderbolt BIOS Assist Mode - Set to "Enabled"
```

When I boot into a virtual console (no DE), and close the lid and later open the lid, I get the error message "**usb 2-3: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM**"

powertop shows 100% for this device:

```
Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
100.0%                  Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
```

cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-3/power/control

```
on
```

cat /sys/power/mem_sleep

```
s2idle [deep]
```

dmesg | grep ACPI | grep supports

```
[    0.400077] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
```

Here is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f3:2610 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the (hopefully) relevant log output:

```
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU1 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU2 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU3 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU4 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU5 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU6 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel:  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: CPU7 is up
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6032
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: thinkpad_acpi: please report the conditions when this event happened to ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 2-3: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 2-3: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 2-3: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 1-9: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4760]
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1094..]
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 kernel: thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd-logind[505]: Lid opened.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd-networkd[390]: eth0: Lost carrier
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd-rfkill[853]: Failed to open device rfkill3: No such device
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Jun 22 17:14:13 x280 systemd-sleep[846]: System resumed.
```